# local variable 'k' referenced before assignment'. Need help to understand why we have this error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code gives an error: `'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment'`. I understand it's because the outer function doesn't pass the parameter, but why does `res = []` works but not `k =0`?

```
class Solution:
    def getPermutation(self, n: int, k: int) -> str:
    res = []
    k = 0

    def backtrack(nums, path):
        if not nums:
            k = k - 1
            if k == 0:
                res.append(path)
            return
        if k < 0: return
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            backtrack(nums[:i] + nums[i + 1:], path + [nums[i]])

    backtrack(list(range(1, n + 1)), [])
    return res
print(Solution().getPermutation(3, 1))
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation, please?

Comment: Simple. Replace k with `self.k`

Comment: @timgeb indentations seems alright

Comment: Because you assign to `k` in the function it becomes a local variable to that function. Then when trying to do `k-1` it is not defined yet (in that function's scope)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002794/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-in-python ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651721/why-am-i-getting-a-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-error

Comment: @Tomerikoo, i think OP is aware of the situation with `k`. Their question is `why does res = [] work but not k =0?`

Comment: @MustafaAydın still, the answer is in those links. The simple reason is that assignment will always work. Doing `k = k-1` is also **reading** the value of `k` which is not yet defined

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes, but by `why does res = [] work`, OP means the further operation of `res.append(..)`, which is not exactly an assignment, is it? (and not exactly reading, either)

Comment: @MustafaAydin, exactly.  A call to the `append` method is not an assignment and therefore doesn't cause the compiler to treat `res` as local to `getPermutation`.

Comment: @DanielWalker You mean `backtrack`. It actually is local to `getPermutation`

Comment: Ah, yes.  That's what I meant.

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry missed that..

Comment: @huyuxiang, did any of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `backtrack` function.  The syntax parser sees that you're assigning `k` to a new value in that first `if` block.  Therefore, the parser has decided that `k` is local to the `backtrack` function, even if that `if` block is not run.

So, suppose you call `backtrack` when `nums` is truthy.  The local variable `k` has not been defined and yet you try to compare it with `0`.

You need to tell the parser that `k` refers to the `k` defined in the higher scope (i.e., `getPermutation`).  You can do this by putting the line

```
nonlocal k
```

as the first line of the `backtrack` function.

The reason you don't have a problem with `res` is it's never assigned to a new value in `backtrack` and so the parser has no reason to assume that it's a local variable.

Comment: You're right.  That would also cause a problem.  However, the point remains that the compiler is treating `k` as a local variable and not as the already defined `k` from the nonlocal scope.

Comment: `k= k - 1` won't be run if `nums` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Object oriented programming. Replace `k` with `self.k` which can be used throughout with the object instance. Python questions about the initialization of  `k` because in one of the `if` condition you are initializing the `k` variable which becomes a local variable and Python suspects that `k` might not have initialized before using it. Simple solution is to use `self.k`. In that case k becomes the property of an instance.

```
class Solution:
    def getPermutation(self, n: int, k: int) -> str:
        res = []
        self.k = 0

        def backtrack(nums, path):
            if not nums:
                self.k = k - 1
                if self.k == 0:
                    res.append(path)
                return
            if self.k < 0: return
            for i in range(0, len(nums)):
                backtrack(nums[:i] + nums[i + 1:], path + [nums[i]])

        backtrack(list(range(1, n + 1)), [])
        return res
print(Solution().getPermutation(3, 1))
```

Comment: Why assign it to `self`?  It's not like the value of `k` needs to be saved once `getPermutation` returns.

Answer (score -1):

You declared both `k` and `res` inside of `getPermutation` method, and they are not visible outside of it.

You should create variable inside init method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.res = []
    self.k = 0
```

Therefore when you create instance of the Solution class, it would have its own `k` and `res` which you can access as `self.k`/`self.res`.

Comment: I think you mean "instance variables" and not "class variables".  Also, doesn't it seem like a waste of memory (not that we're talking about much here but still) to permanently hold on to `k` and `res` even after `getPermutation` returns?

Comment: You are right, I got confused because of the indentation, somehow missed getPermutations().
Since he calls backtrack recursively, I don't see the other way than that, since values would be overwriten whenever backtrack is executed. He could also pass them as parameters, with the default values set to 0 and [].

Comment: I just ran a simple test case (slightly too long to post in this comment) and the `nonlocal` keyword takes care of any issues coming from recursion.

Comment: You got the point about the memory, but I personally would favor instance variable over nonlocal. He could potentially have tens of methods and declare k somewhere else, it's pretty common variable name. I would gladly waste couple of bytes in favor of code simplicity.

Comment: But the tens of methods wouldn't be sharing the same `k`.